# google finance python package not working for some stocks

Tags: python, json, regex, google-finance, stockquotes

This is functional code for retrieving stock prices.

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
import re


def get_last_trade_price(TICKER):
    Asset = json.dumps(getQuotes(TICKER))
    raw = (json.loads(Asset)[0]["LastTradePrice"])
    raw = re.sub(',','',raw)        
    return float(raw)
```

This function retrieves the last traded price of the stock.

```
get_last_trade_price('AAPL')
```

But it does not work for some of the stocks listed in other exchanges outside the US.

```
get_last_trade_price('C52')
```

This [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=SGX:C52&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecRozi3w8sc9YSm9SWtOXmPU4OIKzsgvd80rySypFJLiYoOyBKT4uHj00_UNDY0qk4uKq3J5AAp2-sY8AAAA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip0ems2PDVAhXFDcAKHRv6ApYQsRUIoAEwEA&biw=1366&bih=638) shows the details of the company. How can I get this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the ticker with the index specified first `SGX:C52`

```
get_last_trade_price('SGX:C52')
```